# Add a button to a navigation toolbar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

How can a button be added to a navigation toolbar in an application which is navigation based?

The rootController is a tableView by default, and this is perfect. I would like to add a "share" button to the navigation controller so that I can attach it to my own method.

How is this done if the navigation bar is added in the code somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do it in code, go to your views `viewDidLoad` method and create a `UIBarButtonItem`

This code will create a button that says share like you wanted and put it on the right hand side of the navigation bar.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share"     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(share)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton;
    [shareButton release];
}
```

Comment: Should it be released straight away?

Comment: You can release it as soon as it has been assigned to a navigationItems leftBarButtonItem or rightBarButtonItem.  If you were to release it before it is assigned to the navigationItem.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourShareAction)] autorelease];


self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes an add button, but you get the idea.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
  target: 
  self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)] 
  autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an UIBarButtonItem and attach it to a root view controller's navigation item. You add a target-action pair when you initialize the UIBarButtonItem object and that action message will be sent to the target on a user tapping on the button.

So if you want the button when the table view is shown, set the UIBarButtonItem to your table view controller's navigationItem.rightBarButtomItem property.